# Pre-processor Directives (#if and #endif) not working in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I had written a simple code to understand the Preprocessor directives in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter any value : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
#if a
    printf("The number you entered is non-zero.\n");
    return 0;
#endif
    printf("The number entered is zero.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

When entered value is zero

```
Enter any value : 0
The number entered is zero.
```

When entered value is non-zero

```
Enter any value : 5
The number entered is zero.
```

As the pre-processor `#if` checks for the next token. If it is zero, the code is skipped and if it is non-zero the code is executed as normal.

But here the code is skipped in both the cases. Can you explain what is wrong here?

Comment: This is why the `if..else` conditional statement exists. otherwise it would have been redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This preprocessor check

```
#if a
...
#endif
```

is performed at compile time and is completely unrelated to

```
int a;
```

For `#if a` to be `true` you need a previous statement such as

```
#define a 42
```

For `#if a` to be `false` you need a previous statement such as

```
#define a 0
```

However if you simply have

```
#define a
```

which in itself is valid, but does not define a testable value, then the compiler will issue an error like

> error C1017: invalid integer constant expression

But having `#define a 42` means you cannot then use `a` to define a variable because

```
int a;
```

will expand to

```
int 42;
```

which is an error.

Comment: So what's the use of this pre-processor? I mean when we `#define a 1` it simply means that we want the code inside the pre-processor command to run, then why one would use pre-processor for it. We can simply then write the code which we want to execute always without the pre-processors.

Comment: Suppose I have an array which has `42` elements. I can hard-code that length in the array definition, and in every loop, or I can `#define ARRLEN 42` and use the *single definition* throughout the code. Macros like this can also be used to control *conditional compilation*.

Comment: You wrote code where the use of the preprocessor is totally completely absolutely inappropriate. There are uses where it is appropriate. You'll learn that eventually.

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder _why one would use pre-processor for it._ Consider  `gcc -o demo demo.c -DDEBUG=1` and inside the code `#if DEBUG ...`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: ... and there are considerable benefits from this practice. One is that you can change the array length at one place at a single definition, and all its usage. Another is that suppose you have a more common value like `8` with different usage in different places. If you want to change one of them from `8` to say `10` then you have to read all of the code in detail to know *which* `8` values need to be changed, and which `8` values concerning a different aspect do not need to be changed. But if you have `#define LENA 8` and `#define LENB 8` their usage is distinct.

Comment: It means the usage of preprocessors is wrong here and will not work for the variables we create?

Comment: Yes, they control the code that is *generated* by the compiler, not how it behaves at run-time. Those lines of code do not even exist in the executable.